# Как менять цвет svg-sprite?

Tags: html, css, svg, спрайт

Собственно, как составить каскад в css, чтобы поменять цвет svg в спрайте?
Перепробовал много разных вариантов, в итоге - ничего не получилось.

Если просто вставить код svg в html - таких проблем не возникает,
обращаюсь к path {fill: black} и всё хорошо работает, а тут логику понять не получается.

```css
use.ewq svg path {
  fill: blue
}
```

```html
<svg style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><symbol viewBox="0 0 25 25" fill="none" id="svg-geo"><g clip-path="url(#aa)"><path d="M12.5498 24.5498C12.5498 24.5498 21.5498 16.0208 21.5498 9.5498C21.5498 7.16286 20.6016 4.87367 18.9138 3.18584C17.2259 1.49802 14.9368 0.549805 12.5498 0.549805C10.1629 0.549805 7.87367 1.49802 6.18584 3.18584C4.49802 4.87367 3.5498 7.16286 3.5498 9.5498C3.5498 16.0208 12.5498 24.5498 12.5498 24.5498ZM12.5498 14.0498C11.3563 14.0498 10.2117 13.5757 9.36782 12.7318C8.52391 11.8879 8.0498 10.7433 8.0498 9.5498C8.0498 8.35633 8.52391 7.21174 9.36782 6.36782C10.2117 5.52391 11.3563 5.0498 12.5498 5.0498C13.7433 5.0498 14.8879 5.52391 15.7318 6.36782C16.5757 7.21174 17.0498 8.35633 17.0498 9.5498C17.0498 10.7433 16.5757 11.8879 15.7318 12.7318C14.8879 13.5757 13.7433 14.0498 12.5498 14.0498Z" fill="#F24957"/></g><defs><clipPath id="aa"><path fill="#fff" transform="translate(.55 .55)" d="M0 0H24V24H0z"/></clipPath></defs></symbol></svg>

<svg>
    <use class='ewq' xlink:href='#svg-geo'></use>
</svg>
```

На всякий случай оставляю пример приведённый в codepen
https://codepen.io/myrumpel/pen/PoyEvox

Comment: Если вы с codeopen скопировали, то как-то не правильно скопировали, я скопировал и нормально цвет меняется

Comment: Евгений, я нашёл ответ на вопрос несколько минут назад, сейчас сижу и пишу ответ. Сидел и экспериментировал в codepen, там всё правильно) Но спасибо за ответ)

Comment: Да тут прикол в том, чтобы не засорять html верхняя часть заполняется в отдельном файле, который подключается к основному и вы выводите svg картинку сокращённым видом где - xlink:href='#svg-geo' указывает на id нужного svg, который вы хотите вывести.

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛи, оно у меня так в проекте и реализовано. Вопрос был в смене цвета у svg, которые тягаются из спрайта. Ответ расписал ниже)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ребятки, час в codepen не прошёл зря, поэтому делюсь с теми, кто не знает ответа на вопрос:

```css
use.test1 {
  fill: red
}
use.test2 {
  fill: purple
}
use.test3 {
  fill: yellow
}
```

```html
<svg aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><symbol viewBox="0 0 25 25" id="svg-geoe"><g clip-path="url(#aa)"><path d="M12.5498 24.5498C12.5498 24.5498 21.5498 16.0208 21.5498 9.5498C21.5498 7.16286 20.6016 4.87367 18.9138 3.18584C17.2259 1.49802 14.9368 0.549805 12.5498 0.549805C10.1629 0.549805 7.87367 1.49802 6.18584 3.18584C4.49802 4.87367 3.5498 7.16286 3.5498 9.5498C3.5498 16.0208 12.5498 24.5498 12.5498 24.5498ZM12.5498 14.0498C11.3563 14.0498 10.2117 13.5757 9.36782 12.7318C8.52391 11.8879 8.0498 10.7433 8.0498 9.5498C8.0498 8.35633 8.52391 7.21174 9.36782 6.36782C10.2117 5.52391 11.3563 5.0498 12.5498 5.0498C13.7433 5.0498 14.8879 5.52391 15.7318 6.36782C16.5757 7.21174 17.0498 8.35633 17.0498 9.5498C17.0498 10.7433 16.5757 11.8879 15.7318 12.7318C14.8879 13.5757 13.7433 14.0498 12.5498 14.0498Z" /><symbol viewBox="0 0 25 25" id="svg-geo"><g clip-path="url(#aa)"><path d="M12.5498 24.5498C12.5498 24.5498 21.5498 16.0208 21.5498 9.5498C21.5498 7.16286 20.6016 4.87367 18.9138 3.18584C17.2259 1.49802 14.9368 0.549805 12.5498 0.549805C10.1629 0.549805 7.87367 1.49802 6.18584 3.18584C4.49802 4.87367 3.5498 7.16286 3.5498 9.5498C3.5498 16.0208 12.5498 24.5498 12.5498 24.5498ZM12.5498 14.0498C11.3563 14.0498 10.2117 13.5757 9.36782 12.7318C8.52391 11.8879 8.0498 10.7433 8.0498 9.5498C8.0498 8.35633 8.52391 7.21174 9.36782 6.36782C10.2117 5.52391 11.3563 5.0498 12.5498 5.0498C13.7433 5.0498 14.8879 5.52391 15.7318 6.36782C16.5757 7.21174 17.0498 8.35633 17.0498 9.5498C17.0498 10.7433 16.5757 11.8879 15.7318 12.7318C14.8879 13.5757 13.7433 14.0498 12.5498 14.0498Z" /></g><defs><clipPath id="aa"><path  transform="translate(.55 .55)" d="M0 0H24V24H0z"/></clipPath></defs></symbol></svg>

<svg>
    <use class='test1' href='#svg-geo'></use>
</svg>
<svg>
    <use class='test2' href='#svg-geoe'></use>
</svg>
  <svg>
    <use class='test3' href='#svg-geoe'></use>
</svg>
```

Во-первых, удаляем из кода **svg-sprite`а** подобные строки:

```css
style="display: none;"
fill="#F24957"
fill="none"
```

Так как мы используем тег **use**, добавляем ему класс и обращаемся к конкретному **svg** таким образом:

```css
use.ewq {
  fill: red
}
```

Здесь мы обращаемся к тегу **use**, у которого есть класс test1 и сразу (**без path**) прописываем **fill**, либо **stroke** (это зависит от того, какая у вас svg (fill - заливка, stroke - обводка))

Таким образом мы можем тягать одну и ту же svg картинку в разные места и стилизовать её по-разному.

Comment: А у меня вопрос есть, проще таким образом подтягивать svg или прописывать через <img src="image.svg">, а потом с помощью JS конвертировать его в svg?

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛи, предложенный Вами способ я не пробовал, но если подумать, то этот вариант (спрайт) будет удобнее и функциональнее:
1) Насколько мне известно, то если подключать svg через img, то эти изображения меньше поддаются изменениям;
2) Здесь плагин собирает все svg в один отдельный файл и мы сниппетом подключаем это изображение, к которому можем обращаться напрямую, помимо этого, svg из спрайтов можно анимировать.
3) Так же, насколько мне известно, файл спрайта кешируется, а уже из него тягаются все svg.
4) И после работы с svg, они не подвергаются никакой дальнейшей обработки.

Comment: Хорошие преимущества. Я пользовался заполнением через img и плюс такого подхода был в том, что контент-менеджер без помощи разработчика сайта мог через админку загружать svg иконки любые и они автоматом преобразовывались в svg и приобретали тот цвет и размер, который был прописан для них в CSS. Дело было в том, что было меню в котором к каждому разделу прилагалась иконка этого раздела и эти разделы могли меняться через админку, и к тому же у этого сайта работали 2 темы, зимняя и летняя, когда переключаешь с зелёной на синюю, все цвета всех иконок на сайте должны были меняться.

Comment: Вообще подходов к загрузке svg очень много я заметил и каждый пользуется тем, что удобней или в зависимости от поставленной цели))

Comment: xlink писать не обязательно

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛи, Что касается загрузкой контент-менеджерами в cms, это хороший момент. Думаю, что если есть много svg-иконок с одинаковыми стилями, что нужно будет задавать стили через родителя, а там, в принципе, можно даже просто код заливать и он будет активироваться. С другой стороны, svg-иконки ведь разные бывают, есть те, к которым нужно обращаться не через **path**, а через **circle**, чтобы задать цвет разным частям иконки. Вообще, думаю, что любой проект должен вести прогер, если нет, то пишем документацию, как что и куда добавлять. Мало ли какою иконку они захотят залить) имхо

Comment: @MonkeyMutant, действительно, спасибо. Попробовал - работает)))

Comment: Правильно, и namespace который отвечает за xlink тоже можно убрать

Comment: @MonkeyMutant, подскажите что почитать, чтобы писать такие короткие svg вручную?

Comment: там не читать - это руками делается - такому не учат - сами до этого доходят - снячала рисуют в векторном редакторе и в коде видят точки - это обычная координата - примерно как на шахматной доске

Comment: @MonkeyMutant, это понял, думаю этот скилл нарабатывается при постоянной практике с svg, а я в этой сфере "иностранец", другое нравится)))

Comment: Ну если хочешь, я могу показать через anydesk как рисовать руками

Comment: @MonkeyMutant, это было бы здорово:)

Comment: Ну тогда нажми на мой ник, в ЛК есть email напиши мне

Answer (score 4):

Со стилями всё стандартно и просто, как в учебниках. Одно не пойму - почему, для создания простейших фигур, столько лишнего в SVG ? Такое пишется вручную, безо всяких редакторов:

```css
svg { display: inline-block; width: 150px; }

use.test1 { fill: red; }
use.test2 { fill: purple; }
use.test3 { fill: yellow; }
```

```html
<svg style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <symbol viewBox="0 0 25 25" id="svg-geo">
      <path fill-rule="evenodd" 
            d="
            M 12.5 25 
            C 12.5 25 3.5 15.5 3.5 9.5 
            A 9 9 1 0 1 21.5 9.5 
            C 22 15.5 12.5 25 12.5 25 Z 
            M 8 9.5 
            A 4 4 1 0 1 17 9.5 
            A 4 4 1 0 1 8 9.5 Z" />
    </symbol>
  </defs>
</svg>

<svg><use class='test1' xlink:href='#svg-geo'></use></svg>
<svg><use class='test2' xlink:href='#svg-geo'></use></svg>
<svg><use class='test3' xlink:href='#svg-geo'></use></svg>
```

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145826/discussion-on-answer-by-umodel----svg-sprite); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.